# iOS swift popToRootViewController fire function in rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, rootview

In my app I go back to rootViewController via:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Now i want to call a function from my rootViewController only when i come back using popToRootViewController. Is there a possibility for this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go about it is to get a reference to the root view controller via `navigationController.viewControllers[0]` before the call to `popToRootViewController(animated:)`, set a boolean flag on it and then use the value of that flag in the root view controller's `viewDidAppear`.

Alternatively, you could use the same approach with `UINavigationControllerDelegate.navigationController(_:didShow:animated:)`, though I'm not entirely sure whether it will be called after popping the controllers programmatically.